# Adding shaders to the style object in WebGLVectorLayerRenderer?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webgl, gis, openlayers

Upgrading from OpenLayers **7.5.0** to **9.0.0**, the earlier spesific style object used in the WebGLVectorLayerRenderer is deprecated, and I am having trouble ajusting to the more standard **webGL** flat style that is now being used.

Old style:

```
this.renderer=new WebGLVectorLayerRenderer(this, {
        fill: {
          attributes: {
            color: ...
          },
        },
        stroke: {
          attributes: {
            color: ...
          },
        },
        point:{
            attributes:{
              speed:...
              }
          },
          vertexShader:`
          ...`,

          fragmentShader:`
          ...
          `
      },
});
```

New flat style:

```
this.renderer=new WebGLVectorLayerRenderer(this, {
   style:{
       "fill-color": ["get", "COLOR" ],
       "icon-opacity": 0.6,
       "stroke-color":  ["get", "COLOR"],
       "stroke-width": 1.5,
   }
});
```

Is it still possible to add shaders in the style object (in my case for point) as it was earlier? I see that I could use the **WebGLPointsLayerRenderer**, which accepts a vertex and fragmend shader in the setup object, but that would limit me to render only points(?).
I can see that there exists a shaderBuilder that might be used somehow, but I am very reluctant to setup my shaders using that, compared to providing it in code.